# Searching Custom Object by Parent account

Tags: master-detail, search

I have a Custom Object which is related to an Account with a Master-Detail relationship. If I search for the Parent Account Name, I do not find however the Custom Object records.

The only solution I have is to go to the Parent Record and look to the related list layout, can I do any better?

Comment: I think you can't do that. I tried to edit Mini Page Layout but it doesn't allows to add related list details.

Comment: I have Account with name 'Test Account' having few contacts, and if I search by that Account name in global search, I see Account as well as Contacts in the search results.